# Displaying an Image in Maui Blazor Desktop app from an External Source

Tags: image, blazor, maui-blazor

This question is similar to other but seems to be quite different.

In am creating a Maui Blazor desktop app and am using, the following tag:
`<img src="https://...jpg" />` However, when I open the application, it does not display. If I place the same image in Github and use the `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/...jpg` URL, it displays properly. Using an IIS server on local machine (`https://localhost/...jpg`, or `127.0.0.1/...jpg`) work in browser but does not render in Maui Blazor. Initially thought this was a CORS or HTTP/HTTPS issue, but that does not make sense to me as Github links work.

Answer (score 0):

The required src attribute specifies the URL of the image.

There are two ways to specify the URL in the src attribute:

1. Absolute URL: Links to an external image that is hosted on another website. Example: `src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/...jpg"`.
2. Relative URL: Links to an image that is hosted within the website. Here, the URL does not include the domain name. If the URL begins without a slash, it will be relative to the current page. Example: `src="img_photo.jpg"`. If the URL begins with a slash, it will be relative to the domain. Example: `src="/images/img_photo.jpg"`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the issue that for one Absolute URL, it does work but for another, Absolute URL with the same image does not.